# On the irreducibility of a polynomial!

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let
$
p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n
$
be distinct prime numbers.
Prove that the polynomial
$$
f(x)=\prod_{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n=\pm1}(x+e_1\sqrt{p_1}+e_2\sqrt{p_2}+\cdots+e_n\sqrt{p_n})
$$
Is irreducible in
$
\mathbb Z[x]
$.

---

This means that the polynomial
$
f
$
is the minimal polynomial of the number
$
\sqrt{p_1}+\sqrt{p_2}+\cdots+\sqrt{p_n}
$
over the field of rational numbers!

Comment: See [radical conjugate roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots#Radical_conjugate_roots).